# Aspect ratio when playing older 4:3 games on a wide screen

Tags: hardware

My problem is that when I play an older game like Stronghold Crusader or other games that use a 4:3 aspect ratio, it gets pulled apart to 16:9 on my widescreen monitor.

Is there a way to prevent this? I don't mind having a black bar on either side, as long as the game looks correct.

Comment: What's the model/brand of your screen?

Comment: I'm using an Acer S235HL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most Acer monitors this can be adjusted trough the monitor's menu.

Press the menu button, then press the < / > buttons to navigate to the settings tab, and adjust the "wide mode" setting.

[Reference: Acer S235HL user manual, page 24](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Acer%20Computers/S235HL/Manual/227661?page=24)

Answer (score 6):

This is often a setting in the graphics driver menu, but the exact location will vary.

For NVIDIA cards, open the NVIDIA control panel, then go to Display > Adjust desktop size and position, and select Aspect Ratio or No scaling on the Scaling tab.

[image]

You may also want to change some of the other options on that page to get a more visually pleasant result; experiment a little.

[AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/UnableToSetGPUScaling.aspx) and [Intel](http://communities.intel.com/thread/28218) have similar options in their driver settings.

Comment: I did try this for Stronghold Crusader, however it had no affect on that game. I will try this on other games, to see if it does work there.

Comment: It's possible that your screen will still adjust the input image no matter what the graphics card is sending. Check your monitor settings as well. Also make sure to set `Perform scaling on:` to `GPU` to ensure you're always sending a highres image (this will degrade performance a bit but won't rely on the monitor's upscaling).

Comment: @Lex: You *may* get the desired results by checking the "Override the scaling mode set by games and programs" and/or scaling on the GPU. I don't have that particular game, so I can't really test this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that also, but it seems that my monitor has its own settings for these things, and that was causing the issue.